# Cannot upgrade Ninject to latest version in Nuget

Tags: nuget, ninject, ninject.web

I have a ASP.NET WebForms application that uses some Ninject packages, but I am stuck at a certain version.  When I try to upgrade to the latest version, I get "Unable to resolve dependencies" issues.

The packages in question are:

```
Package                       InstalledVer   LatestVer
------------------------------------------------------
Ninject                       v3.2.2         v3.3.4
Ninject.Web                   v3.2.1 ✔      v3.2.1
Ninject.Web.Common            v3.2.3         v3.3.1
Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost    v3.2.3         v3.3.1
```

If I try updating `Ninject`, I get:

> Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Ninject 3.3.4' is not compatible with
>   'Ninject.Web 3.2.1 constraint: Ninject (>= 3.2.0 && < 3.3.0)'

but `Ninject.Web` is already at the latest version!

Should I change the Dependency behaviour of `Ninject.Web` or would this be unsafe?  If I do, what should I change the Dependency behavior to?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, so this is how to fix:

1. Remove the `Ninject.Web` package completely.  This package is no longer required as it is now integrated into `Ninject.Web.Common` (well, version v3.3+  anyway)
2. Update the packages `Ninject`, `Ninject.Web.Common` and `Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost`.  These should now upgrade okay. For me, they are both v3.3.1.
3. As part of the package upgrade a new file `App_Start\Ninject.Web.Common.cs` will have been added.  This is just a rename of the existing  `App_Start\NinjectWeb.Common.cs` so either [a] delete the new file or [b] migrate over your Ninject module registrations and remove the old file.
4. In `web.config`, you should now remove the `OnePerRequestModule` module:

   ```
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="OnePerRequestModule" type="Ninject.Web.Common.OnePerRequestHttpModule" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
   ```

   This is because this module, is registered dynamically on loadup in the `App_Start\Ninject.Web.Common.cs` file's `Start()` method:

   ```
   public static void Start()
   {
       DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
       DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
       bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
   }
   ```

   If you don't remove this entry from web.config then you can expect a type exception when launching your application, not least because as part of the version update, the class has moved from the `Ninject.Web.Common` namespace to `Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost`.
5. You can also remove the file `App_Start\NinjectWeb.cs` for the same reason (registering `NinjectHttpModule`)
6. If `OnePerRequestHttpModule` doesn't resolve in `App_Start\Ninject.Web.Common.cs` then add the following using statement to the file `using Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost;` (I think this is a missing reference in v3.3.1 of the package.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: I didn't have the original error message, but  these steps were extremely helpful nonetheless, as the update created the additional Ninject.Web.Common.cs file and lacked the using statement in step 6.

Comment: Package `Ninject.Web.Common 3.3.1` doesn't contain classes like `HttpHandlerBase, PageBase, WebServiceBase`. How does one replace them ?     @Chris Walsh

Comment: @ptp Sorry, not sure.  Have you checked `Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost`?